# Fixing a leader board in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, leaderboard

Whenever someone finishes the quiz it doesn't show their score. It deletes it and shows everyone elses. But it does show their's the next time someone else plays. How would I fix this? I am relatively new. I have tried changing some things but it always results in an error message! Any help/advice would be awesome.

```
import time
start1 = time.time()
            question_af1 = ("How many countries are in Africa?")
            option_af1 =(" a. 54 \n b. 50 \n c. 47 \n d. 38")
            print(question_af1)
            print(option_af1)    
            answer_af1 = input(">")        
            if answer_af1.lower() == "a":
                score += 100
                print("Correct, score =", score)#add time not used
                #print(end - start) will show seconds completed
            else:
                print("Incorrect") #the correct answer is

            question_af2 = ("What is the largest country in Africa?")
            option_af2 = (" a. Algeria \n b. Sudan \n c. Ethiopia \n d. Zimbabwe")


            end1 = time.time()
            print(round(end1 - start1,2))###finish fixing time
            print("Score =", score)

            import csv

            score=score
            username=name

            with open ("leaderboard1.csv", "a", newline='') as file:
                fields=['score', 'name']
                writer=csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fields)
                writer.writerow({'score' : score, 'name' : username})

            with open ("leaderboard1.csv", "r") as file:
                sortlist=[]
                reader=csv.reader(file)
                for i in reader:
                    sortlist.append(i)
            for i in range(len(sortlist)):
                if i != 0:
                    sortlist[i][0]=int(sortlist[i][int(0)])


            print("")
            for i in range(len(sortlist)):
                (sortlist[i])


            for i in range(555):
                for i in range(len(sortlist)):
                    if i != 0:
                        if sortlist[i][0] < sortlist[i+1][0]-1:
                            change=sortlist[i]
                            sortlist[i]=sortlist[i+1]
                            sortlist[i+1]=change
```

Comment: It would helpful to see some example data from your leaderboard1.csv file.

Comment: I believe if you play this multiply times you will be able to have different names in mine. All that would be in there is for example, 'Jessica' '700'

Comment: Use a free IDE like PyCharm Community Edition to find the problem by stepping through the code a statement at a time in the IDE's debugger.  It may be a tedious process but you will see what the code is actually doing.

Comment: I downloaded Pycharm but it says I need a python interpreter. Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you currently using to run your Python code?